# How I can fill my DropDownList with Data from a XML File in my ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, drop-down-menu

I have a ASP.NET Application with a DropDownList and I want it fill with my XML File Values. 
How I can I use my XML for this that I create a new item for every Value in my XML.

**My XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="resources">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Werk" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />        
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <resources>
    <Werk>foo1</Werk>      <!-- The first Value-->
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <Werk>foo2</Werk>      <!-- The second Value-->
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <Werk>foo3</Werk>      <!-- The third Value-->
  </resources>
</NewDataSet>
```

**In my ASPX:**

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XMLData" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/Werke.xml" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dropWerk" runat="server" Width="245px" />
```

I need a kind of a Method that fill my DropDownList with the Data from the XML File

tarasov

**CS File:**

```
private void BindXML()
        {
          XmlDocument xmldoc = XMLData.GetXmlDocument();

          using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
          {
              ds.ReadXml(XMLData.DataFile);
              dropWerk.DataSource = ds;
              dropWerk.DataTextField = "Werk";
              dropWerk.DataBind(); 
          }
        }
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far, hopefully you are not expecting people to write this all for you.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to your second week on SO! What have you tried yourself? Is there any specific piece of code you're having trouble with?

Comment: @ChrisBint : look in my CS File Code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Method:**
store the xml in a data set and then assign it to dropdownlist

```
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("xmlfile.xml");

dropWerk.DataSource = ds; or dropWerk.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; 
dropWerk.TextField = "field name"; // field to display in dropdown
dropWerk.ValueField="Value Field";
dropWerk.DataBind();
```

**Updated Answer:**
**2nd Method:** add one by one value to your dropdownlist items
If I understand your question from the comments you want to add xml values to list items
try this

```
XmlDocument xdoc=new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load("xmlfile.xml");

XmlNodeList node = xdoc.SelectSingleNodes("/NewDataSet/resources/");
foreach(XmlNode n in node )
{
ListItem l = new ListItem();
    l.Text = n.InnerXml.ToString();
    drpWerk.Items.Add(l);
}
drpWerk.DataBind();
```

Comment: @Tarasov now what is your problem ?

Comment: I want create a new ListItem with this Value of <Werk>. If I start my Program I get a empty DropDownList :(

Comment: @Tarasov There is a mistake in your code: ds.ReadXml(XMLData.DataFile); dont specify xmldatasource in the readxml method just give the xmlfilename eg ds.ReadXml("xmlfile.xml"); or see my answer.

Comment: @Tarasov in which page event you are calling Bind Method ?

Comment: @Tarasov your code seems to right, place a breakpoint at  ds.ReadXml(XMLData.DataFile); then right click and see the table contains the data or table is null

Comment: I bind it in the Page_Load Method and I have a Error by ds.ReadXml(XMLData.DataFile); Errortext: A part of Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\~\App_Data\Werke.xml" couldn't found

Comment: @Tarasov ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/xmlfile.xml")) use this method. ~ represent site root, if youx xml is located at the root of the site if it is in app_code then it should be ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/appCode/xmlfile.xml"));

Comment: my xml file is in the app_data folder and I think I can get the path abaout DataFile="~/App_Data/Werke.xml" from the ASPX File

Comment: yes but you have to use the Server.MapPath method like this `ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Werke.xml"));` otherwise the path will be wrong

Comment: OK the path is right now...but XmlNodeList node = xdoc.SelectSingleNodes("/NewDataSet/resources/"); give me a error with (a Inplizite Convert from system.xml.xmlnode to system.xml.xmlnodeList ist not allow :(

Comment: XmlNodeList nodes = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Werk"); is the right way ans so it works :)

Comment: @Tarasov welcome. Yes you can also get it by GetElementsByTagName.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script runat="server">  
    protected void dropWerk_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {  
        Label1.Text = dropWerk.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();  
}  
</script>  
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/YourXmlFile.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropWerk" runat="server" Width="245px" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropWerk_OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
```

You may want to put a breakpoint in dropWerk_OnSelectedIndexChanged handler and examine dropWerk.SelectedItem to get ideas how to better use the passed value

Comment: I don't know what you mean with the  Label1.Text = dropWerk.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();  because I create a new ListItem with the Value of the XML Value :/

Answer (score 0):

The Solution:

```
private void BindXML()
        {
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument(); 

          xmldoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Werke.xml"));

          XmlNodeList nodes = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Werk");

            foreach (XmlNode n in nodes)
            {
                ListItem l = new ListItem();
                l.Text = n.InnerXml.ToString();
                dropWerk.Items.Add(l);
            }

            dropWerk.DataBind();

        }
```

bind this Method in the Page_Load Method and it works :)