# How to bind my DDL from XML Data Source in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, data-binding, ddl

I have a xml file which is given to me by client so i can't change it it looks like this:

CodeBase.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CATALOG>
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <orderByTitleDesc />
  <CD>
    <CodeBase>hellow</CodeBase>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <CodeBase>http://KL1225K7/EViewer/Client/EvCtrl6En.cab#version=9,4,2,9</CodeBase>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <CodeBase>31 amrch testing for font</CodeBase>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <CodeBase>CodeBase2</CodeBase>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <CodeBase>Ser</CodeBase>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <CodeBase>ZaidiTest</CodeBase>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <CodeBase>test222</CodeBase>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

I want to bind this xml with this in  ddl

I am writing the code in code behind file as follows:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string filePath = Server.MapPath("CodeBase.xml");
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            ds.ReadXml(filePath);
            ddlCodeBase.DataSource = ds.Tables["1"];
            ddlCodeBase.DataTextField = "CodeBase";
            ddlCodeBase.DataValueField = "CD";
            ddlCodeBase.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Client side code as Follows:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCodeBase" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

But i am getting empty DDl (No data in it). Please Let me know Guys what to do.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can fill my DropDownList with Data from a XML File in my ASP.NET Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646031/how-i-can-fill-my-dropdownlist-with-data-from-a-xml-file-in-my-asp-net-applicati)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code . its working fine for me.

```
 string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Cities.xml");
using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
{
    ds.ReadXml(filePath);
    ddlCities.DataSource = ds;
    ddlCities.DataTextField = "CodeBase";
    ddlCities.DataValueField = "CodeBase";
    ddlCities.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: When I Debug till Last in  gives me Error like this                      An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'CodeBase'.

Comment: Change file name i used cities.xml

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //fillDDL();

        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/CodeBase.xml");
        //using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        //{
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(filePath);
        ddlCodeBase.DataSource = ds.Tables["CD"];
        ddlCodeBase.DataTextField = "CodeBase";
        ddlCodeBase.DataValueField = "CodeBase";
        ddlCodeBase.DataBind();

        // }
    }

Comment: By Adding this to my Code   ddlCodeBase.DataSource = ds.Tables["CD"];

Comment: if my code helpful for you then voted me .@BasantGera